# How can I change the text color with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, text

When I hover a text with animation definitely I will use jQuery. Is there a code that will change the color, or size?

Comment: Side note - any styling you can do with CSS you can handle with jQuery.

Answer (score 379, accepted):

Place the following in your jQuery `mouseover` event handler:

```
$(this).css('color', 'red');
```

To set both color and size at the same time:

```
$(this).css({ 'color': 'red', 'font-size': '150%' });
```

You can set any CSS attribute using the `.css()` [jQuery function](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS).

Answer (score 7):

Or you may do the following

```
$(this).animate({color:'black'},1000);
```

But you need to download the color plugin from [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color).

Answer (score 5):

Nowadays, animating text color is included in the jQuery UI Effects Core.  It's pretty small.  You can make a custom download here: http://jqueryui.com/download - but you don't actually need anything but the effects core itself (not even the UI core), and it brings with it different easing functions as well.

Answer (score 0):

use CSS instead of jquery

transition:

```css
div:hover {
    transition: all 1s;
    color: orange;
    font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<div>lorem</div>
<div>ippsum</div>
<div>dolor</div>
```

or different animation:
[CSS Tricks | 4 Ways to Animate the Color of a Text Link on Hover](https://css-tricks.com/4-ways-to-animate-the-color-of-a-text-link-on-hover/)