# Change text color using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a radio button like this

```
<input type='radio' name='specific_consultant' id='specific_consultant_no' 
                                                                      value='no'>No</input>
```

on `.on click` of this radio button , I need to change text color like No .. how do i do it..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the text color with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001366/how-can-i-change-the-text-color-with-jquery)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var button = $('#specific_consultant_no');
    button.click(function() {
        button.css('color', 'FOO');
    });
});
```

if you want to reuse the method, you can do eg.

```
var colorMethod = function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'FOO');
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    var button = $('#specific_consultant_no');
    button.click(colorMethod);
});
```

you can also use the [addClass](http://docs.jquery.com/Addclass) and [removeClass](http://docs.jquery.com/Removeclass) methods, to be more flexible!

Comment: i added like  $('#specific_consultant_no').css('color','red');
 but did not work ....

Comment: is your id unique on your page - following the standards, it has to be!

Comment: does your assignment of the css-attribute be in a click-eventHandler? please support more code, so that i can help you!

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function:

```
$(function() {
    $('#specific_consultant_no').click(function() {
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
    });
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#myButton").on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('green');
        $("#result").toggle();
});
```