# Let users to change the color of text

Tags: javascript, jquery

User wants to change the color of the text through php .I am new in Php can someone guide me How to do this ? I was trying this through jquery function. Yellow Red Blue

```
$("select").change(function () {
    var ID = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
    $('#selectBox').css('color', ID);
});
```

Comment: `.change` is an event handler, it is run _once_ something changes

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [tag:php]; what's your (relevant/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) HTML, and what action is the user supposed to take to trigger the colour-change?

Comment: change when??onclick onblur?

Comment: Why do you use some element's  ID as a color for another element?

Comment: @Punit - Please check this Stack Question it may help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941679/change-text-color-using-jquery](Click)

Comment: @Daniel onclick and onblur are events i know that.But change happens on occurance of an event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest, in the absence of any HTML in the question:

```
// binds the change to a select element (_ALL_ select elements):
$("select").change(function () {
    // assigns the value of the selected option to the 'color' variable
    var color = $(this).val()

    /* changes the CSS of the '#selectBox' element, to set the color
       and updates the text of that element to reflect the chosen option/color:
    */
    $('#selectBox').css('color', color).text(color);
// triggers the change event, to trigger the change-handler on page-load/DOMready
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fbTCf/).

Coupled with the following HTML:

```
<select name="color" id="color">
    <option value="red">red</option>
    <option value="blue">blue</option>
    <option value="green">green</option>
</select>
<div id="selectBox"></div>
```

Note that, if you have multiple `select` elements on the page, you *must* use a more specific selector to bind the correct event-handling (unless all the `select` elements are there to update the same CSS of the same element).

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to check which `<option>` has been selected. Whenever an `<option>` has been selected your `<select>` element get the selected `<option>`s value. So you can just get the value:

```
$("select").change(function () {
    var color = $(this).val()
    $('#selectBox').css('color', color);
});
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uJtK5/)

---

You can't use php for this as you want to modify the DOM element which is client-sided, where php is only server-sided.