# jquery - change text color

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Jquery and I'm trying to get started by simply changing the color of the font when I hover over it. I thought that I put the right code in but it's not working? can someone help me get this going?

SHOW.JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".modal").hover(function(){
 $(".modal").css("color","red");
}));
```

SHOW.HTML.ERB:

```
 <p class="modal"><%= @subscriber.last_name %></p>
```

APPLICATION.JS:

```
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //= require turbolinks
 //= require_tree .
```

This is all my code. I just wanted to keep it simple at first.

Comment: Have you included the `jQuery` library ? Do share browser-rendered code instead of ruby code...

Comment: I think so. I'm posting the file (UPDATED)

Comment: Any errors? What's the current behavior?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the text color with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001366/how-can-i-change-the-text-color-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andros Rex's method works perfectly - however you may actually want something more like this instead - it changes the color back to the previous color when the mouse is no longer over the element.

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        var old;
        $(".modal").hover(
            function() {
                old = $(".modal").css("color");
                $(".modal").css("color","red");
            },
            function() {
                $(".modal").css("color",old);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are missing closing parentheses. This is how it should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".modal").hover(function() {
    $(".modal").css("color","red");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.modal').css({"color" : "red"});
```