# Turning css colors into Javascript colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to customize these colors using javascript but Ive only found ways to do it with CSS

```
.tabs .tab a {
  color: #90caf9;
}
.tabs .tab a:hover,.tabs .tab a.active {
  background-color:transparent;
  color:#008B9B;
 }
.tabs .indicator {
  background-color:#009BAD;
 }
 .tabs .tab a:focus.active {
   color:#26a69a;
   background-color: rgba(55, 55, 55, 0.2);
 }
```

Comment: The only way to do it is qith jQuery. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001366/how-can-i-change-the-text-color-with-jquery

Comment: Can you explain what you mean better? What do you mean by Javascript colors?

Comment: use css variables if you want to change colors on the fly.

Comment: HOW do you want to customize them?

Comment: @R10t-- jQuery is *never* the only way to do it. [JavaScript's come a long way in the nine years since that question was asked.](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#set_style)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using JQuery

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('a, .tab').css({"color": '#821122'});
      $('a, .tabs').css({"color": '#821122'});
      $('a, .active ').css({"color": '#821122', "background-color": "#821122"});
      $('a:focus, .active ').css({"color": '#821122', "background-color": "#821122"});
    });
    </script>
```