# Changing color of text color based on value switch case statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

How do I change the color of the value displayed in a table with different colors, if `urgent` then text color red for an example? Its a value from the back-end.

**Javascript**

```
var priority = objs[i].priority;
switch(objs[i].priority)
{
    case '1': priority = "Urgent"; break;
    case '2': priority = "Major"; break;
}
tr.find(".td_priority").text(priority);
```

Comment: You can create a class for each priority.

Comment: As your example doesn't make full sense to me, here's a general approach on how to change a text color with jQuery: `$(element).css('color', 'red');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the text color with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001366/how-can-i-change-the-text-color-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the color for text use **.css('color', 'red').**

it will be like.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
objs = 1;
var priority = objs;
var color ='';
switch(objs) //in your case use objs[i].priority. I used objs for example
{
  
  case 1: priority = "Urgent"; color = 'red'; break; //if it's Urgent, add color red
  case 2: priority = "Major"; color = 'green'; break; //for example if it's Major, add color green
}

$('tr').find(".td_priority").text(priority).css('color', color); //for text add css


});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="td_priority"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: tq sir your answer did helped me

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `css` method present on jquery
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp

Or

If the text colors are pre-defined.. You can create different classes for the colors and just update the className based on switch

Answer (score 0):

```
In Here The problem might be You check case as a string value.But I think 
objs[i].priority returns an integer value not string type.

In Your Answer
==============
var priority = objs[i].priority;
switch(objs[i].priority) 
{
//checks case as a string so value of priority does not changes (Does not 
//true the case)
  case '1': priority = "Urgent"; break; //checks case as a string so nothing changes
  case '2': priority = "Major"; break; //checks case as a string so nothing changes
}
tr.find(".td_priority").text(priority);

-------------------------------------------------------------------------

So try this,
============

var priority = objs[i].priority;
switch(priority)
{
  case 1: priority = "Urgent"; break; //Remove Quote Marks
  case 2: priority = "Major"; break; //Remove Quote Marks
}
tr.find(".td_priority").text(priority);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try something like**

```
var myown = objs[i].myown; 
switch(myown) 
{ 
case 1: 
myown = "Green"; 
break; 
case 2: 
myown = "Red"; 
break; 
}
```

**and then**

```
tr.find(".td_pmyown").text(myown);
```

Hope this will help you out